# Highlight shape differences between two images with color change

Tags: python, image, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to make my code more robust compared to my first revision. The goal is to generate a final single image by comparing image A and image B to get image C. Currently I am working to show differences in images composed of black lines.  In this case, that would be image A and B. I have a working method with imaging resizing and the pre-processing done (resizing, noise reduction, etc). The code I developed to show the differences (image C) is shown below:

```
np_image_A = np.array(image_A)
np_image_B = np.array(image_B)

# Set the green and red channels respectively to 0. Leaves a blue image
np_image_A[:, :, 1] = 0
np_image_A[:, :, 2] = 0
# Set the blue channels to 0.
np_image_B[:, :, 0] = 0
# Add the np images after color modification
overlay_image = cv2.add(np_image_A, np_image_B)
```

I currently don't feel that is is robust enough and may lead to some issues down the line. I want to use a method that shows the image differences between image A and B in a single image. And image A be assigned one color for differences and image B be assigned another color (such as blue and red, and black represents areas that are the same). This is highlighted in the image below:
[image: image differences]

To remedy this, I received some help from StackOverflow and now have a method that uses masking and merging in OpenCV. The issue that I have found is that only additive changes are shown, and if an item is removed, it is not show in the difference image.

Here is the updated code that gets me part of the way to the solution that I am seeking.The issue with this code is that it produces what is found in image D and not image C. I tried to essentially run this block of code twice, switching img = imageA and imageB, but the output is mangled for some reason.

```
    # load image A as color image
    img = cv2.imread('1a.png')
    # load A and B as grayscale
    imgA = cv2.imread('1a.png',0)
    imgB = cv2.imread('1b.png',0)
    # invert grayscale images for subtraction
    imgA_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(imgA)
    imgB_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(imgB)
    # subtract the original (A) for the new version (B)
    diff = cv2.subtract(imgB_inv, imgA_inv)
    # split color image A into blue,green,red color channels
    b,g,r = cv2.split(img)
    # merge channels back into image, subtracting the diff from
    # the blue and green channels, leaving the shape of diff red
    res = cv2.merge((b-diff,g-diff,r))
    # display result
    cv2.imshow('Result',res)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The result that I am looking for is image C, but currently I can only achieve image D with the revised code.

Edit: Here are the test images A and B for use.
[image: Test Image A]
[image: Test Image B]

Comment: Please upload your images. I want to test your code on the images.

Comment: @BarzanHayati The test images have been separately uploaded in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, but you need to create two separate diffs. One diff represents the black pixels that are in A but not in B, and the other diff represents the black pixels that are in B but not in A.

Result:
[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load A and B as grayscale
imgA = cv2.imread('1a.png',0)
imgB = cv2.imread('1b.png',0)
# invert grayscale images for subtraction
imgA_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(imgA)
imgB_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(imgB)

# create two diffs, A - B and B - A
diff1 = cv2.subtract(imgB_inv, imgA_inv)
diff2 = cv2.subtract(imgA_inv, imgB_inv)
# create a combined image of the two inverted 
combined = cv2.add(imgA_inv, imgB_inv)
combined_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(combined)
# convert the combined image back to rbg, 
# so that we can modify individual color channels
combined_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(combined_inv, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
# split combined image into blue,green,red color channels
b,g,r = cv2.split(combined_rgb)
# merge channels back into image, adding the first diff to
# the red channel and the second diff to the blue channel
res = cv2.merge((b+diff2,g,r+diff1))
# display result
cv2.imshow('Result',res)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Your answer is not correct! How you generate C and D by your code? I don't add negative to your answer.

Comment: Ah! I was missing the bitwise not after creating the two diff images when I attempted it. I think that is what left me with a mangled output when I tried. That you very much for your help! -Cheers

Comment: @JuliusDariusBelosarius What?